# Custom Design Area

Tags: template, design

We have some templates relating to our store(s) but not actually part of the Magento; they sit on a remote server (SagePay hosted payment forms). To help us keep track of the hosted templates we'd like to add them to the main site's source control repository so we always have easy access to them. I've been trying to decided where to place them within the directory structure. I figured a logical place might be to create my own {area} and store the files in `app/design/offsite/`, `app/design/hosted/` or something along those lines.

Are there any problems with this approach?

Magento lists frontend themes in various places which it presumably generates by iterating over the folders inside the frontend area, but I'm not aware of anything that could cause issues or even end up displaying my new 'area' to the Magento users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the files to `app/design/offsite` without any issues.
When showing some information about the available themes magento only loops through the folders under the `frontend` and `adminhtml` areas.

An other option would be just to have the templates in `ROOT/some_folder` and make sure you add `.htaccess` to that folder so the resources won't be accessible for the "public".